# How to Preserve state of tabs in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using this script for the tabs in JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false;
}).filter(':first').click();
});
</script>
```

but I really want to find out how to preserve the state of tabs using that code and without using any other plugin, any idea?

Comment: Is the state not persisted in the DOM? i.e. to find wich tab is selected you could run $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a.selected');?

Comment: what do you mean by preserve the state??? Be a little bit clear

Comment: Did you want to persist beyond page refreshes maybe?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer too! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look into something like [store.js](https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/store-js). It will let you store information on the client side for a given domain, and retrieve it on subsequent page loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an external code or plugin and don't mind not supporting IE 7, you could always use Local Storage. It's new to HTML 5 and allows you simply to save key value pairs to the browsers local storage using javascript. So if you wanted to save the value 'foo' under the key 'bar' you could do something as simple as:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
```

And to retrieve

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("foo");
```

This website shows you what its supported on:

http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

And this is a good page for learning a bit about it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

There are two options with local storage

- Local storage - This is persisted beyond page refreshes
- Session storage - This is persisted while the browser session is still active. When you close your browsers tab, the storage is lost.

Hope this help[s!

Andy